# Is there any way to Active PIXEL lines of Scene in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Is there any way to active Scene's pixel lines? I know there is GridPane but that is not good to measure the pixels. I want to active the Pixel lines of Scene to view each pixel location clearly.

Comment: Could you explain? I'm not sure what you mean with "pixel line" in this context. I also don't know "active" as verb, did you mean "activate". Also what do you mean by "measure pixels" (everything else sounds like you want to **draw** something, not to read/calculate something)?

Comment: @fabian I need the pixel box on the Scene. as Adobe Photoshop have after zooming. or Something like this one. http://hajsoftutorial.com/javafx-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ddcdc1.gif